# Binary Search Tree JavaScript implementation - remove function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Here's my implementation for a Binary Search Tree in JavaScript. All functions appear to be working properly except for the `remove` function. Specifically, it seems to be removing nodes properly until there's 2 nodes left in the tree:

```
var binaryTreeNode = function (value) {
  return {
    value : value,
    left  : null,
    right : null
  };
};

var binarySearchTree = function () {
  var tree  = Object.create( binarySearchTreeMethods );
  tree.root = null;
  return tree;
};

var binarySearchTreeMethods = {

  insert: function (value, node) {
    var newNode = binaryTreeNode( value );

    // check if tree is empty
    if ( this.isEmpty() ) {
      this.root = newNode;
      return;
    }

    // initialize node
    if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;

    // compare value with node.value
    if ( value <= node.value ) {
      // check if left exists
      if ( node.left ) {
        this.insert( value, node.left );
      } else {
        node.left = newNode;
      }
    } else {
      if ( node.right ) {
        this.insert( value, node.right );
      } else {
        node.right = newNode;
      }
    }
  },

  remove: function (value, node) {
    var nextRightValue, nextLeftValue, minRight;

    if ( !this.isEmpty() ) {
      // initialize node
      if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;

      // compare the node's value with the value
      if ( value < node.value ) {
        // check if there is a left node
        if ( node.left ) {
          node.left = this.remove( value, node.left );
        }
      } else if ( value > node.value ) {
        // check if there is a right node
        if ( node.right ) {
          node.right = this.remove( value, node.right );
        }
      } else {
        // at this point, value === node.value
        // check if node is a leaf node
        if ( node.left === null && node.right === null ) {
          // edge case of single node in tree (i.e. root node)
          if ( this.getHeight() === 0 ) {
            this.root = null;
            return this.root;
          } else {
            node = null;
          }
        } else if ( node.left === null ) {
          node = node.right;
        } else if ( node.right === null ) {
          node = node.left;
        } else {
          // node has both left and right
          minRight   = this.findMinValue( node.right );
          node.value = minRight;
          node.right = this.remove( minRight, node.right );
        }
      }
      return node;
    }
  },

  contains: function (value, node) {
    if ( this.isEmpty() ) return false;
    // tree is not empty - initialize node
    if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;

    // check if node's value is the value
    if ( value === node.value ) return true;
    if ( value < node.value ) {
      // check if left node exists
      return node.left ? this.contains( value, node.left ) : false;
    } else {
      // check if right node exists
      return node.right ? this.contains( value, node.right ) : false;
    }
  },

  findMaxValue: function (node) {
    if ( !this.isEmpty() ) {
      if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;
      while ( node.right ) {
        node = node.right;
      }
      return node.value;
    }
  },

  findMinValue: function (node) {
    if ( !this.isEmpty() ) {
      if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;
      while ( node.left ) {
        node = node.left;
      }
      return node.value;
    }
  },

  getHeight: function (node) {
    if ( !this.isEmpty() ) {
      // initialize node
      if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;

      // base case
      if ( node.left  === null && node.right === null ) return 0;
      if ( node.left  === null ) return 1 + this.getHeight( node.right );
      if ( node.right === null ) return 1 + this.getHeight( node.left );
      return 1 + Math.max( this.getHeight( node.left ), this.getHeight( node.right ) );
    }
  },

  isEmpty: function () {
    return this.root === null;
  }

};
```

Inserting values into the binary search tree works fine:

```
var bst = binarySearchTree();
bst.insert(10);
bst.insert(5);
bst.insert(20);
bst.insert(30);
bst.insert(22);
bst.insert(18);
```

**I come across an issue when I start removing the `root` value each time:**

```
bst.remove(10); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(18); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(20); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(22); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(30); // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE OCCURS
```

Prior to removing 30, the tree only has two values: 30 as the root value and 5 as the root.left value. I would expect that removing 30 would give me a tree which has 5 as the root. However, removing 30 doesn't do anything to the tree; it remains the same.

Further testing shows that if I had removed 5 first and then 30, then everything works fine as well:

```
bst.remove(10); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(18); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(20); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(22); // this works fine and the resulting bst tree is structurally correct
bst.remove(5);  // Results in a tree with 30 as the root value
bst.remove(30); // Results in the empty tree where root === null
```

**Can anyone help me understand why removing 30 initially didn't work?**

Comment: Consider not initialising *left* and *right* as in `left  : null`, so when inserting, instead of `if ( node.left )` you'd have `if ('left' in node)`, otherwise if the value is 0 you might get strange results. Same when removing: if there is no *left*, remove the property. Not to sure about `node === void 0`, why not `node === undefined`? Ok, it's 3 more characters to type but more expressive.

Comment: @RobG Even if `node.left.value` is 0, `node.left` will always be truthy if `node.left` is present.

Comment: I would also say that having the having a BST that _deletes_ its nodes' `.left` and `.right` properties in order to clear them would be pretty weird in terms of OOP design. Most of the world's BSTs don't do that (most languages don't even allow you to do that).

Comment: @JLRishe—then why does it return false if `node.left` is *null*? Or *undefined*? Or *false*? See [*ECMA-262 §12.5 step 2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5). Javascript isn't "most languages". Why have a left property if there is no left node? Makes sense to me. Using *null* to indicate no left node means that the tree can't store a value of *null*. I don't see where the OP has limited the tree to certain values.

Comment: @RobG I don't understand your first question or why you referred me to the JS spec for `if` statement. Why does _what_ return false? You seem to be unfamiliar with the typical design of binary trees (and misunderstanding OP's implementation). The tree _can_ store a value of _null_, or any other value. The tree consists of a hierarchy of `binaryTreeNode`s, and each of those nodes can contain any value the user desires (although I'm not sure how much sense it makes to store a null value in a binary search tree).

Comment: @RobG And JavaScript may not be "most languages", but even in JavaScript it's not typical to `delete` and re-add properties from objects to indicate that the property does or does not have a value. In a data structure, such as a binary search tree, the data objects are defined to have certain properties, and sometimes those properties are null to indicate that they don't have a value. If your design relies heavily on the distinction between `if('value' in object)` and `if(object.value)`, then you are setting yourself up for trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has a provision for the case when the found node is the root and it is the only node in the tree, and if a node has both a left and a right child, you overwrite its value. But when the node to remove is the root and it has only one child, there is nothing in your code that overwrites `this.root`, and you don't overwrite the root's value, so it is not removed and the tree remains unmodified.

You can fix this by changing this:

```
if ( node === void 0 ) node = this.root;

// compare the node's value with the value
if ( value < node.value ) {
```

to this:

```
if ( node === void 0 ) {
    this.root = this.remove(value, this.root);
// compare the node's value with the value
} else if ( value < node.value ) {
```

---

Once that is fixed, you can simplify your logic a bit:

```
remove: function (value, node) {
    if (!this.isEmpty()) {
        // initialize node
        if (!node) {
            this.root = this.remove(value, this.root);
        } else if (value < node.value && node.left) {
            node.left = this.remove(value, node.left);
        } else if (value > node.value && node.right) {
            node.right = this.remove(value, node.right);
        } else if (value === node.value) {
            // check if node is a leaf node
            if (node.left && node.right) {
                // node has two children. change its value to the min
                // right value and remove the min right node
                node.value = this.findMinValue(node.right);
                node.right = this.remove(node.value, node.right);
            } else {
                // replace the node with whichever child it has
                node = node.left || node.right;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
},
```

and then you can simplify it further by separating it into two methods:

```
remove: function (value) {
    this.root = this._removeInner(value, this.root);
},

_removeInner: function (value, node) {
    if (node) {
        if (value < node.value) {
            node.left = this._removeInner(value, node.left);
        } else if (value > node.value) {
            node.right = this._removeInner(value, node.right);
        } else if (node.left && node.right) {
            node.value = this.findMinValue(node.right);
            node.right = this._removeInner(node.value, node.right);
        } else {
            node = node.left || node.right;
        }
    }
    return node;
},
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7sdmk61b/1/)**

---

@wmock has asked how I went about solving this problem so I'll elaborate on that a bit.

The first thing I did was walk the code in the debugger, focusing on the `bst.remove(30)` part. I noticed that 30 was the root at that point and that it remained there after `remove()` was done. This led me to noticing that the code never modifies the root in that particular case.

I then looked at how the return value of `this.remove()` was being assigned to `node.left` and `node.right`, and with some recollection of BST algorithms, thought it would make sense to emulate that for the root as well. And that was indeed the answer.

There were a few things that motivated splitting the method into two methods:

- I noticed that the method had a fair amount of special-case functionality that was only relevant for the initial call to `bst.remove()`

  - Checking `this.isEmpty()`
  - Using `this.root` for the value of `node` if `node` was null
  - Resetting `this.root` to null under certain cases when the tree height is 0

It seemed sloppy to be doing all of that in every pass through `remove()`

- I also repeatedly found myself wanting to use `if (!node)` to check whether I had reached the edge of the tree, but I couldn't because there was that special case logic to use `this.root` when `node` was null.

Splitting the method into two parts resolved all of the above issues.

Note that in a lot of BST implementations, the functionality in `_removeInner()` would be a method on the `binaryTreeNode` type, and the tree would just interact with the root node. That eliminates the need to pass a node from one method call to the next:

*In `binarySearchTree`*:

```
remove: function (value) {
    this.root && this.root.remove(value);
},
```

*In `binaryTreeNode`*:

```
remove: function (value) {
    if (value < this.value) {
        this.left = this.left && this.left.remove(value);
    } else if (value > this.value) {
        this.right = this.right && this.right.remove(value);
    } else if (this.left && this.right) {
        this.value = this.right.findMinValue();
        this.right = this.right.remove(this.value);
    } else {
        return this.left || this.right;
    }
    return this;
},

findMinValue: function () {
    return this.left ? this.left.findMinValue() : this.value;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5p9heqg/1/)

Comment: in my original code, the reason I'm testing for `node === void 0` was simply to initialize `node` to `this.root` when I called `remove` without passing a `node` value in the parameter. I'm not sure I follow how your suggestion will fix the `remove` issue - can you clarify further?

Comment: @wmock You have designed your algorithm to follow a path through the tree and replace each node along the path with its "new self", which will be either (a) itself, possibly with its `.value` modified, (b) its left or right child (c) null. That is what you are doing here: `node.left = this.remove( value, node.left );`. But in the case of the root, you are not following that pattern and are leaving the root untouched in the case when it should be removed and replaced with its left or right child. The above remedies that.

Comment: I'll definitely play around with your solution and work through the logic to understand it better! Will get back to you soon.

Comment: @wmock Cool. And please see the `bst.values()` method I added in my jsfiddle. That will allow you to quickly inspect the tree's contents.

Comment: thank you so much! Your code is very clean and fixes the issues my implementation had. Can I ask what was your thought process in terms of fixing the issue? I had tried to dig around for quite a bit, and was not successful - would love to learn more about how you approached it!

Comment: @wmock See my (rather lengthy) response above.

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes. Seriously, this has been tremendously helpful and I really appreciate you taking the time out to explain your thought process! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the full example of a Binary tree with **insert** and **remove** functionalities

```js
function Node(val) {
    this.data = val;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
}

function BST() {
    this.root = null;
    this.insert = insert;
    this.inOrder = inOrder;
    this.remove = remove;
    this.removeNode = removeNode;
    this.kthSmallestNode = kthSmallestNode;
}

function insert(val) {
    if (val == null || val == undefined)
        return;

    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = new Node(val);
        return;
    }

    var current = this.root
    var newNode = new Node(val);

    while (true) {
        if (val < current.data) {
            if (current.left == null) {
                current.left = newNode;
                return;
            }
            current = current.left;
        } else {
            if (current.right == null) {
                current.right = newNode;
                return;
            }
            current = current.right;
        }
    }

}

function remove(val) {
    this.root = removeNode(this.root, val);
}

function removeNode(current, value) {
    if (value == null || value == undefined)
        return;

    if (value == current.data) {
        if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (current.left == null)
            return current.right;
        else if (current.right == null)
            return current.left;
        else {
            var tempNode = kthSmallestNode(current.right);
            current.data = tempNode.data;
            current.right = removeNode(current.right, tempNode.data);
            return current;
        }


    } else if (value < current.data) {
        current.left = removeNode(current.left, value);
        return current;
    } else {
        current.right = removeNode(current.right, value);
        return current;
    }
}

function kthSmallestNode(node) {
    while (!(node.left == null))
        node = node.left;

    return node;
}

function inOrder(node) {
    if (!(node == null)) {
        inOrder(node.left);
        console.log(node.data + " ");
        inOrder(node.right);
    }
}


var tree = new BST();
tree.insert(25);
tree.insert(20);
tree.insert(30);
tree.insert(27);
tree.insert(21);
tree.insert(16);
tree.insert(26);
tree.insert(35);

tree.remove(30)

console.log("Inorder : ")
console.log(tree.inOrder(tree.root))
```

**Good Luck!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty simplified answer that I think most people will understand and it takes into account children nodes. The key is that if you are removing a value with a right and left child that you first go left and then all the way right because this assures you that it will have no children and be easier to update.

```
  removeNode(val) {
    let currentNode, parentNode, nextBiggestParentNode=null, found=false, base=[this.root];
    while(base.length > 0 && !found) {
      currentNode = base.pop();
      if(currentNode.value === val) {
        found=true;
        if(!currentNode.left && !currentNode.right) {
          parentNode.right === currentNode ? parentNode.right = null : parentNode.left = null;
        }
        else if(!currentNode.right && currentNode.left) {
          parentNode.right === currentNode ? parentNode.right = currentNode.left : parentNode.left = currentNode.left;
        }
        else if(!currentNode.left && currentNode.right) {
          parentNode.right === currentNode ? parentNode.right = currentNode.right : parentNode.left = currentNode.right;
        }
        else {
          let _traverse = node => {
            if (node.right) {
              nextBiggestParentNode = node;
              _traverse(node.right);
            }
            else {
              currentNode.value = node.value;
              nextBiggestParentNode ? nextBiggestParentNode.right = null : currentNode.left = null;
            }
          }
          _traverse(currentNode.left);
        }
      }
      else {
        parentNode = currentNode;
        val > currentNode.value && currentNode.right ? base.unshift(currentNode.right) : base.unshift(currentNode.left);
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
```

that code is part of a class, here is the rest of my constructor code if anybody is interested

```
let TreeNode = class  {
  constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
}

let BST = class {
  constructor(root=null) {
    this.root = root;
  }

  insert(nodeToInsert) {
    if (this.root === null) {
      this.root = nodeToInsert;
    } else {
      this._insert(this.root, nodeToInsert);
    }
  }

  _insert(root, nodeToInsert) {
    if (nodeToInsert.value < root.value) {
      if (!root.left) {
        root.left = nodeToInsert;
      } else {
        this._insert(root.left, nodeToInsert);
      }
    } else {
      if (!root.right) {
        root.right = nodeToInsert;
      } else {
        this._insert(root.right, nodeToInsert);
      }
    }
  }
```

here is some demo code to create a bst and remove a value

```
let bst = new BST();
const nums = [20,10,5,15,3,7,13,17,30,35,25,23,27,37,36,38];
function createBst() {
  for (let i of nums) {
    bst.insert(new TreeNode(i));
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(bst, null, 2));
  bst.removeNode(35);
}
createBst();
console.log(JSON.stringify(bst, null, 2));
```